# SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when trying to run gulp

Tags: laravel, gulp, centos

I am new to gulp but on a existing laravel project I needed to add some css I was told to update the app.sass and then run gulp to compile it. I tried to follow a guide called [Compiling Assets (Laravel Elixir)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir) to compile the sass file but ran into problems. To get everything installed correctly I updated our bootstrap.sh file in the vagrant setup to include nodejs, npm, gulp and laravel-elixir. Once the changes were made I loaded the vagrant box and I verified that I have the following versions.

```
[vagrant@localhost project-css]$ gulp -v
[18:12:38] CLI version 1.4.0
[18:12:38] Local version 3.9.1
[vagrant@localhost project-css]$ npm -v
3.10.10
[vagrant@localhost project-css]$ node -v
v6.11.1
```

When I try to run gulp I get

```
/vagrant/src/project-css/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:349
  if (n <= 0 || state.length === 0 && state.end

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/src/project-css/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/readable.js:12:30)
```

The full project I'm working on is available on github at [Rockefeller-css](https://github.com/wvulibraries/rockefeller-css/tree/trying-searchy)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried pulling in a newer node version?   I know we have issues with laravel-mix on Node LTS (6.11).

Comment: I used sudo yum --showduplicates list nodejs | expand to check and see what versions were available and only see 1:6.11.1-1.el7 listed

Comment: I was able to get node to v7.10.1 by running 'curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash' - and then 'yum install -y nodejs' but this didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue on my own by adding the following to my bootstrap.sh file

```
rpm -ivh https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/http-parser/2.7.1/3.el7/x86_64/http-parser-2.7.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum install -y nodejs
```

Also after vagrant was finished loading and I was able to ssh into the box in a custom setup-vagrant.sh script that needed to be ran I was able to add the following command.

```
sudo npm install
```

Their was already a cd into the laravel project folder and their was a package.json file that existed. After that I was able to cd into the project folder and run gulp correctly.